# How to place a dynamic table in openXml wordprocessing document?

Tags: openxml-sdk

Using an OpenXml document, there are content controls where the data gets added based on the data from the database for that record; but now? Need to add a dynamic Table where it could have from 1 to 10 rows.  always has 5 columns.

Getting the data to put in is easy, they will be driven by variables.  so they can be named Row 1 column 1, col 2, col3, col4 and col5;

I can make  variables to say useRow1 (to 10) = true/false; these are the #using defines:

```
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
    using OpenXmlPowerTools.Commands;
    using OpenXmlPowerTools;
```

each set of table rows will depend on which record it is.  The choices are to add rows or just make a static table with 10 rows where the bottom ones are blank?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create a fonction that return your dynamic Table.
The fonction build the table depending your datas, and you only add the needed rows.

```
public Table CreateTable(params type[] datas)
{
     Table table = new Table();

     foreach(Type line in par.rows)
     {
          Row row = new Row();
          ...
          table.Append(row);
     }
     return table;
}
```